# Trying to retrieve discord messages from discord channel

Tags: laravel, discord

I am trying to retrieve messages that are in a Discord channel with laravel.
In my response I can see all sorts of information like the author and timestamp, but I can't manage to see the content as it is empty

Like this: (left out the other information because of security reasons):

```
 0 => array:16 [▼
    "content" => ""
  ]
```

I have created a Discord bot and given it all the rights that were possible so that I wouldn't accidentally miss anything. Also I created this controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DiscordMessageController extends Controller
{
    public function getMessages()
    {
        $client = new Client([
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bot YOUR_BOT_TOKEN',
            ],
        ]);

        $response = $client->get('https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/CHANNEL_ID/messages');

        $messages = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

        return response()->json($messages);
    }
}
```

And this is how my routing looks like:

```
Route::apiResource('discord-messages', DiscordController::class);
```

Comment: If you haven’t fixed this, you need to make sure you have message intent enabled in the developers api section.